# Simplify $\frac{x^{2}-4x}{x^{3}+2x^{2}-5x-6}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify $$\frac{x^{2}-4x}{x^{3}+2x^{2}-5x-6}$$

[Attempt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kfr7zrcjzds7vsr/2013-10-08%2016.28.33.jpg).

I get $$\frac{-\frac{5}{6}}{x+1}+\frac{\frac{-4}{15}}{x+3}+\frac{\frac{21}{10}}{x-2}$$ but it's wrong.

Comment: May be you have a typo? And we have $x^2-4$ in the numerator?

Comment: @jacob: It looks like you swapped $21/10$ and $-4/15$. If you swap those two constants, it works out. Did you transcribe it wrong or associate the wrong constants?

Answer (score 1):

It looks right to me. (WA [thinks you're right too](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E2%20-%204x%29/%28x%5E3%20%2b%202x%5E2%20-5x%20-6%20%29).) If you're submitting your answer online, perhaps you need to change the fractions in the numerator, so that it's in this form: $\frac{-{5}}{6({x+1})}$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \frac{x^3-4x}{x^3+2x^2-5x-6} = \frac{x\cdot(x-2)\cdot(x+2)}{(x+1)\cdot(x-2)\cdot(x+3)} = \frac{x.(x+2)}{(x+1)\cdot(x+3)}$

Now Using Partial fraction Method::

$\displaystyle \frac{x^2+2x}{(x+1)\cdot(x+3)} = \frac{A}{(x+1)}+\frac{B}{(x+3)}$

$\displaystyle x^2+2x = A(x+3)+B(x+1)$

Now Put $x+1 = 0\Leftrightarrow x = -1$

We Get $\displaystyle A = -\frac{1}{2}$

and again Put $x+3 = 0\Leftrightarrow x = -3$

We Get $\displaystyle B = -\frac{3}{2}$

So $\displaystyle \frac{x^2+2x}{(x+1)\cdot(x+3)} = -\frac{1}{2(x+1)}-\frac{3}{2(x+3)}$

Comment: Oh Sorry I have no noticed that there is a $x^2-4x$. I have take $x^3-4x$ Sorry from my side. but process is Right

Comment: Maybe it should be $x^3-4x$? :)